# Cassandra- Ubuntu : Connection remotely is refused

Tags: cassandra

I have a problem when I want to connect to Cassandra remotely I run it on ubunto server and can connect to it through cassandra-cli connect localhost/9160 But when I connect remotely I have an error Connection Refused

Can some one help me what the problem? Is it for firewall or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Edit rpc_address to a public one in cassandra.yaml.

Comment: Thanks , I did that and I changed the listen port to 0.0.0.0 but it didn't work for me. I turned off firewall too but same result.